# Ignoring escaped delimiters (commas) with awk?

Tags: awk, delimiter, escaping

If I had a string with escaped commas like so:

```
a,b,{c\,d\,e},f,g
```

How might I use awk to parse that into the following items?

```
a
b
{c\,d\,e}
f
g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
   split($0, a, /,/)
   j=1
   for(i=1; i<=length(a); ++i) {
      if(match(b[j], /\\$/)) {
         b[j]=b[j] "," a[i]
      } else {
         b[++j] = a[i]
      }
   }
   for(k=2; k<=length(b); ++k) {
      print b[k]
   }
}
```

1. Split into array `a`, using '`,`' as delimiter
2. Build array `b` from `a`, merging lines that end in '`\`'
3. Print array `b` (Note: Starts at 2 since first item is blank)

This solution presumes (for now) that '`,`' is the only character that is ever escaped with '`\`'--that is, there is no need to handle any `\\` in the input, nor weird combinations such as `\\\,\\,\\\\,,\,`.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  gsub("\\\\,", "!Q!")
  n = split($0, a, ",")
  for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    gsub("!Q!", "\\,", a[i])
    print a[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: This will work as long as you **never** have `!Q!` in your text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think awk has any built-in support for something like this. Here's a solution that's not nearly as short as DigitalRoss's, but should have no danger of ever accidentally hitting your made-up string (!Q!). Since it tests with an `if`, you could also extend it to be careful about whether you actually have `\\,` at the end of your string, which should be an escaped slash, not comma.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}

{
    curfield=1
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (substr($i,length($i)) == "\\") {
            fields[curfield] = fields[curfield] substr($i,1,length($i)-1) FS
        } else {
            fields[curfield] = fields[curfield] $i
            curfield++
        }
    }
    nf = curfield - 1
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s   ",i,fields[i])
    }
    printf("\n")
}
```

Comment: I assumed that this was all the splitting you were interested in doing, and therefore set FS to split on commas. If you're trying to do this just on a substring, use system PAUSE's version of the same method.